# Cannot convert sheet row to class error in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to remove rows with duplicate values base on the last row in google sheet using a script. In this case, it will be the row with values of "hi" but I'm not sure how to resolve this error:

*Cannot convert Mon Dec 31 2018 00:15:41 GMT+0800 (HKT),hi to (class). (line 18, file "Code")*

Here is my code:

```
// retrieve sheet data and store into variable
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

// get last row value from column B(target column)
var col_len = data.length
var lastRow = data[col_len-1][1];
var index = new Array();

function check_dup(){
  for(i=0; i<data.length;i++){
    if(lastRow === data[i][1]){
      index.push(i);
    }
  }

  //error from this line
  for(i=index.length-2;i>=1;i--){
    sheet.deleteRow(data[index[i]]);
  }
}
```

[image: sheet]

Comment: Are you really performing the first several lines in the global namespace and not within a function? In other words, you make it possible for any later code -- even in different files -- to modify those variables (`sheet`, `data`, `col_len`, `index`, etc.) to different values and types without any indication that already written code may be affected.

Comment: I tried adding lines in the global namespace but still received the same error. The issue has been resolved. Thank you for your reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Delete All Rows that have same data in column2 as last row

As I understand your problem is to delete all rows that match that have the same data in column 2 as the last row.

```
function removeDup() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var targetData=data[data.length-1][1];//last row column 2 is target data 
  var d=0;//number of rows deleted 
  for(var i=1;i<data.length-1;i++){ //start at one to skip header row and don't go to last row
    if(data[i][1]==targetData){//if it matches targetData then delete row
      sheet.deleteRow(i-d+1);
      d++;//increment delete counts because the row got delete the data array is still the same size.
    }
  }
}
```

The are many answers on the subject of removing duplicate rows on stack overflow.  Do a little searching and you'll find them.

Comment: It works now! I'll do that in the future, thank you for the advice :)